# MongoDB Aggregation : Date Comparison in Filter not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get the logs and orders processed in a day using the below:

but if i use $eq the results always return empty.  but if i use $gte for the date comparison ($$order.LogDate) then i get the order count.  but the matching data is available in the DB. any idea where i'm doing it wrong? i also tried using $gte and $lte with  the date and date+1 day. still no luck:

```
{ 
  "_id" : 0,
   "FirstName" : { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$drivers.FirstName", 0] },
   "LastName" : { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$drivers.LastName", 0] },
   "PhoneNumber" : { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$drivers.ContactNo", 0] },
    "LogDate" : "$_id.LogDate",
    "LogDateEnd":{ $add: [ "$_id.LogDate", 86400000 ] },
    "TotalMinutes" : "$TotalMinutes", 
    "OrderCount" : { 
            "$size" : {
               "$filter" : { 
                 "input" : "$orders", 
                 "as":"order",
                 "cond" : { 
                   "$and" : [{ "$eq" : ["$$order.OrderStatus", "COMPLETE"] },{ "$eq" : ["$$order.LogDate", "$LogDate"] }] 
                   } 
                 } 
               } 
            } 
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample doc or reproducible scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're comparing dates unless they are identical a match will not occurs.

```
ISODate("2018-07-05T07:14:59.191+0000")
ISODate("2018-07-05T07:14:59.192+0000")
```

Even though these dates are practically identical that 1 millisecond difference is enough to make the `$eq` operator to return false.

In your case where you want all `orders` from a certain day. all you have to do is match using date expressions like [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) like so:

```
"OrderCount": {
    "$size": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$orders",
            "as": "order",
            "cond": {
                "$and": [
                    {"$eq": ["$$order.OrderStatus", "COMPLETE"]},
                    {"$eq": [{$year: "$$order.LogDate"}, {$year: "$LogDate"}]},
                    {"$eq": [{$month: "$$order.LogDate"}, {$month: "$LogDate"}]},
                    {"$eq": [{$dayOfMonth: "$$order.LogDate"}, {$dayOfMonth: "$LogDate"}]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will leave the orders from the day of the year that `$logDate` is at.

Comment: HI , when passing the $LogDate to the $and or inside i get the following error " "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type missing to Date", "

Comment: I just assumed `logDate` is a `date` type field but this error says it's not, you should use the `date` field you do have ( `LogDateEnd`?) instead.

Comment: Actually LogDate is a type ISODate

Comment: "`BSON type missing`", i.e the field is missing. either way it's not `date` type.

Comment: thank for the help. the issue was i had to pass the "_id.LogDate" instead of the LogDate which is a computed value in the above.